# BuildFire: Cant add plugin to shared app, nor can remove it from Plugin Manager

Tags: plugins, buildfire

Two questions here. I've created a plugin for a co-worker and have permission to their app, but I can't add the plugin to their app as it doesn't appear in the list, but it does show in the list for my directly owned apps. Is there any way to to allow this?

Second, we decided that I'll just have him upload the plugin and add it to the app that way, but it sees the plugin already exists (likely because I uploaded it in my account.) But there doesn't seem to be any way to remove any plugins you upload to the Plugin Manager. So how do we remove it?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are several ways to install a plugin on your app. I'll discuss the two most popular ways. The first is to submit it to the marketplace. if approved, all apps will have access to your plugin for free or at a price. The second is for private plugins. For this method, you need to issue a license key from your developer portal.
   [image]

The receiving party would then install the plugin through their marketplace. Note:  they need to be on a tier to allow this.
see the green button on the top right corner
[image]

2. Plugin names are unique. You'd need to rename the deprecated copy so the new version can be accepted with the official plugin name.